# SQL Selecting a value between 2 special characters where more than one special character exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple query:

```
LEFT(ReportMasterID, CHARINDEX(':', ReportMasterID) - 1) AS cons
```

I need to work out a variation of the script above that will pull back only the value between 2 special chars where there are more than one set of special chars in the string.

Here is the format of the string I need to pull the value from:

```
BORMG01D:BORMG:111111:1251624:40200
```

Obviously the above select generates an error because there are more than one set of special chars - I just need this value:

```
BORMG
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple XML approach

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,ReportMasterID varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'BORMG01D:BORMG:111111:1251624:40200')

Select ID
      ,Pos2 = convert(xml,'<x>'+replace(ReportMasterID,':','</x><x>')+'</x>').value('/x[2]','varchar(100)')
 From @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Pos2
1   BORMG
```